# Create Docusign envelope that uses social authentication using the REST API

Tags: docusignapi

I'd like to allow users/recipients to authenticate when signing using their facebook or google credentials.  How do I create an envelop with Docusign's rest API to allow social authentication?

Specifically, how do I configure a signer recipient to authentication via Facebook?  The documentation mentions the socialAuthentications field but specifies it as a boolean and describes it as a list: [documentation](https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#REST%20API%20References/Recipients/Signers%20Recipient.htm)

More specifically, which fields should I add to the following signer to require facebook authentication:

```
"Signers": [{
  "email": "signer.name@company.com",
  "name": "Mike Signer"
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

To require that a Signer authenticate via Facebook, include the **requireIdLookup** attribute and **idCheckConfigurationName** as follows:

```
"signers": [
    {
      "routingOrder": "1",
      "name": "John Doe",
      "email": "jdoe@test.com",
      "recipientId": "1",
      "requireIdLookup": "true",
      "idCheckConfigurationName": "Facebook"
    }
]
```